# INDEX/MATCH Returning the wrong value. What did I do wrong?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to create an spreadsheet where INDEX/MATCH automatically populates monthly sales goals. However, it is returning the wrong number.

[image]

In cell B6 I want the value to be 10000. In columns G and H, I've set the goals and the corresponding date in the hopes of matching the goal to the date in row 2.

B6 is returning "6000" AND "7/19/2015" in an adjacent cell when it should just be returning "10000" ... and I don't know why.

In H6 the goal for the 7/12/2015 is set at 10,000 from cell G6, which corresponds to the date in B2, so I don't know why it is returning the date AFTER the one I'm matching.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second part of the formula, the match part, needs to have "H3:H9", not G.  The match is looking for your B2 (a date) in the range $G$3:$G$9, which is numbers so there won't be a return of the date.

Edit: And @Jeeped makes a good point, since the dates are going to be found in your table, you would probably be better using "0" instead of "1" at the end - "0" will look for an exact match. If you keep 1, it might return a false positive (return a date that is NEAR your lookup date, not the exact one).

Comment: Also "H3:H9" and "G3:G9" have to be locked since the formula is being copied over.

Comment: As the dates in B2:E2 seem to have direct correlation with the dates in H3:H9, I would also suggest that using 0 as the *match_type* parameter in the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Agree with @Jeeped that when using Match, one should generally only use "1"/"-1" as a parameter when you (a) have sorted data and (b) want your function to return an approximate amount. ie: if you have a list of interest rates based on dates, excluding holidays, and you want the function to return you the number close to your desired date if it does not appear.

Answer (score 2):

Place in B6 and copy across:

```
=INDEX($G3:$G9,MATCH(B2,$H3:$H9,1))
```