# Excel: Is it possible to use Vlookup to look for a value by using 2nd or 3rd column, and return the value from the first column?

Tags: excel, vlookup

Consider a data file like this

```
    A       B           C       D
    8256241 524CS-18    8204    $2.96 
    8256248 14212CS-18  8204    $3.96 
    8262898 1012CS36    8204    $1.96 
     129620 500868      8029    $0.72 
     129885 502237      8029    $3.17 
     129907 50850       8029    $3.58 
     229405 6905585550  8237    $109.88 
     229413 6905585679  8237    $129.88
```

I want to lookup a value from column B or C, and then return a value from A. How can I do that using specifically Vlookup function?

I tried this

```
    VLOOKUP(500868,OFFSET('Sheet Name'!A2:D8,0,1),2,FALSE)
```

this looks up the value in column B instead of A, but can only return value from C or D. How can I retrieve value from A instead.?

Comment: Try `index/match`. Edit: going to try (and fail) to answer before Scott XD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INDEX/MATCH Returning the wrong value. What did I do wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298561/index-match-returning-the-wrong-value-what-did-i-do-wrong)

Answer (score 4):

Looking up column B and returning column A. `F1` is where I placed the value you're looking for.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$8,MATCH(F1,$B$1:$B$8,0))
```

Comment: you must be reading my mind today.  You beat me twice just now.  Just as I was about to comment you edited and answered the question I was going to post.

Comment: Ahhh yea, I realized `F1` is kinda random. Thank you for letting me win <3

Comment: Index/Match is absolutely the way to go. (Don't forget to anchor your ranges though!)

Comment: @ScottCraner how do you copy the data though? When I do it, it all pastes into one cell per row XD

Comment: @BruceWayne anchor meaning `$`?

Comment: Text to Columns delineated on the space.

Comment: Yeah - or I guess "make the references absolute"? I'm not too sharp on my Excel formula semantics :/

Comment: FWIW with a simple INDEX/MATCH you can do full column references without detriment.  `=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(F1,$B:$B,0))`

Comment: So what makes it complex?

Comment: If you turn it into an Array formula.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is. There are 2 options:

### VLOOKUP

[Check out how you can combine VLOOKUP + IF or CHOOSE to lookup on other columns.](https://www.atlaspm.com/toms-tutorials-for-excel/tom%E2%80%99s-tutorials-for-excel-using-vlookup-for-reverse-lookups/)

### INDEX MATCH

[Link here](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/)
or

**INDEX** - returns row (cell) from the `[RETURN_COLUMN]`

**MATCH** - returns index of `[LOOKUP_VALUE]` within `[LOOKUP_COLUMN]`

`=INDEX([RETURN_COLUMN],MATCH([LOOKUP_VALUE],[LOOKUP_COLUMN],0))`